# Chrome extension that can open URLs

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, history

There are some extensions for Google Chrome browser - History 2, Better History Manager, etc. I need this one, but with feature of open URLs of founded via search masks. For example, I open my history with this extension and type 'youtube.com/watch'. So I see Youtube URLs from my history. Now, by default, I must open each of them by hands. Is there such an extension, with 'Open these URLs in tabs' or something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to open each one in your history, or just a select few? Because you can just middle-mouse click the select few you want to watch.

Comment: Mostly yes, the first of it. For example, I deleted the history of Youtube by mistake. I search all URLs which contains '*www.youtube.com/watch*' for open them. I will open each of them for a long time by hands. This extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-2/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp isn't bad, but there's no option which I'm looking for.